# sqlite3:Unable to close due to unfinalised statements

Tags: exception, sqlite

I have two sqlite connections and execute like below(CMyDatabase is a derived class of sqlite3):

```
CMyDatabase* dbConnection1 = new CMyDatabase;
dbConnection1->OpenDataBase(CQCommon::GetModulePath() + L"test.db");

CMyDatabase* dbConnection2 = new CMyDatabase;
dbConnection2->OpenDataBase(CQCommon::GetModulePath() + L"test.db");

dbConnection2->BeginTrans();
CString updateStr("update ImageAlbumEntry set ImageID = 2 where ID = 1;");
dbConnection2->ExecNoQuery(updateStr);
CString queryStr("select ImageID from ImageAlbumEntry where ID = 1;");
CppSQLite3Query queryResult;
dbConnection2->ExecQuery(queryStr, queryResult);
cout<<queryResult.getIntField(0)<<endl;
dbConnection2->EndTrans(TRUE);

dbConnection2->CloseDataBase();
dbConnection1->CloseDataBase();
```

Now when I invoke dbConnection1->CloseDataBase(). I met with the error stated as 'Unable to close due to unfinalised statements'. Can anyone explain the reason and resolve method of the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Please reformat your question with your commands in a code block to improve readability

Answer (score 8):

Depends on which wrapper you are using. I'm guessing you are using one similar to [cppSQLite3](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2006/korsan/API/PapaganAnimationEditor/class_cpp_s_q_lite3_query.html)

If that is true, then you need to issue a **CppSQLite3Query::finalize** command to to tell sqlite3 that you are done with your query.

From the sqlite3 documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html)

**sqlite3_finalize()**
This routine destroys a prepared statement created by a prior call to sqlite3_prepare(). Every prepared statement must be destroyed using a call to this routine in order to avoid memory leaks.