# Unable to close sqlite3 database with ruby

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite

```
begin
    db = SQLite3::Database.open "dbfile.db"
    dbins = db.prepare("INSERT INTO table(a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?);")
    dbins.execute(vala,valb,valc)
rescue SQLite3::Exception => e
    puts("Something went wrong: " + e)
ensure
    db.close if db
end
```

So that would be the code I use to open an SQLite3 database and write data to it.
My problem is that this code always gives me the following error:

```
unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups
```

If I remove the `db.close if db` part it works, but after several hours of the script running I get the `too many open files` error. Please do not advise me to raise my inode file limit, that would only be a temporary solution to a greater problem.

I do not want the script to just keep the database open forever, whenever an event happens I want it to open the db, write the data, and close it again, just how it's expected to work.

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25988110/9138821) answer isn't helping because of the reason in the comment, which is true.

What do I have to do to "finish" the statement so I can close the database? I have tried to just add a `sleep(5)` before closing the database, but that had no effect.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373369/sqlite3unable-to-close-due-to-unfinalised-statements) Q suggesting to use [finalize](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) on the statement, but that seems to be only relevant for the C/C++ interface and not for ruby's sqlite3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the source code for the ruby gem helped. Specifically the file [statement.c](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/blob/b6862d8f2542ce795ac6374ab1b1ddd08af8fd4d/ext/sqlite3/statement.c)'s following codeblock:

```
/* call-seq: stmt.close
 *
 * Closes the statement by finalizing the underlying statement
 * handle. The statement must not be used after being closed.
 */
static VALUE sqlite3_rb_close(VALUE self)
{
  sqlite3StmtRubyPtr ctx;

  Data_Get_Struct(self, sqlite3StmtRuby, ctx);

  REQUIRE_OPEN_STMT(ctx);

  sqlite3_finalize(ctx->st);
  ctx->st = NULL;

  return self;
}
```

So using `.close` on the statement (e.g. `dbins.close` after the `.execute` in my code) will finalize the statement and make me able to close the database file.